# Radio button form validation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm doing form validations using jquery all fields are working fine but only `checkbox` and `radio button` are not validating and both radio buttons will be checked how should I do can anyone suggest me according to my code where is the problem.
if any mistakes in the form feel free to tell.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('.success_msg').hide();

 /* name*/ 
 $('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var regex = /^([^0-9]*)$/;
  var is_name=regex.test(input.val());
  if(is_name){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
   
  }
 });
  
 /* E-mail */ 
 $('#contact_email').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var regex = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
  var is_email=regex.test(input.val());
  if(is_email){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* Phone */ 
 $('#contact_phone').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var regex =  /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  var is_phone=regex.test(input.val());
  if(is_phone){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* message*/
 $('#contact_message, #contact_enquiry').keyup(function(event) {
  var input=$(this);
  var message=$(this).val();
  if(message){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  } 
 });

 /* Radio button */


 $('#contact_male, #contact_female').click(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked")){
   $(this).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
     }
     else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
   $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
     }
 });

 /* Checkbox */


 // $('#contact_check').click(function(){
 //     if($(this).is(":checked")){
 //   $(this).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
 //     }
 //     else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
 //   $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
 //     }
 // });

 
  /* Submit */
 $("#submit_form").click(function(event){

  var form_data = $("#contact").serializeArray();

  var error_free = true;
  for (var input in form_data){
   var element = $("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name']);
   var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
   var error_element = $("span", element.parent());

   if (!valid){
    error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show"); error_free=false;
   }
   else{
    error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
   }
  }

  if (!error_free){
   event.preventDefault(); 
  }
  else{
   $('.success_msg').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
   $('input , textarea , select').val('').removeClass('valid');
   event.preventDefault();
  }

 });
   
});
```

```css
.success_msg {
    width: 350px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(213, 255, 187, 0.7);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
}
.iva-nav {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: all 0.74s ease;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
.iva-nav span {
 transform: translateZ(8px);
 -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
.iva-nav:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.4);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 50;
}
.iva-nav:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.4);
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 25;
}
.iva-nav:hover:before {
 transform: rotate(225deg);
 background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.6);
 border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.1);

}
.iva-nav:hover:after {
 transform: rotate(133deg);
 background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.6);
 border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.1);
}
.fancy-heading-s1 {
 max-width: 1400px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 40px;
 padding: 25px 0;
 color: #ffffff;
} 
.fancy-heading-s2 {
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 color: #fff;
}
.fancy-title {
 display: block;
 font-size: 13px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.cfar-s1 .cfar-heading {
 text-align: center;
}

*:focus{ outline: none;}

.cfar {
 max-width: 1140px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cfar-s1 {
 padding: 40px 100px;
 background-color: #313439;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span:after {
 content: " . ";
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 transform: translateY(-15%);
 margin: 0 10px;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span:last-child:after {
 content: "";
 margin-right: 0;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-heading-s2 h2 {
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-heading-s2 h2 span {
 color: #da4e5b;
}
.cfar-s1 form {
 padding: 30px 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.cfar .detail {
 position: relative;
 margin: 20px 0;
 flex-basis: 48%;
}

.cfar .detail input,.detail textarea,.detail select {
 display: block;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 padding: 5px 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.cfar option { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); }
.cfar .detail textarea {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 resize: none;
}

.cfar .detail label {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
 pointer-events: none;
 transition: all 0.43s ease-in-out;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 transition: all 0.43s ease-in-out;
}
.cfar .detail input:focus:after,.detail textarea:foucs:after,.detail select:focus:after,
.cfar .detail .inputBar:focus:before, 
.cfar .detail .inputBar:focus:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 0;
 background: red;
 height: 2px;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar:after { right: 50%;}

.cfar .detail .inputBar:before { left: 50%;}

.cfar .detail input:focus ~ label,
.cfar .detail input:valid ~ label,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus ~ label,
.cfar .detail textarea:valid ~ label {
 top: -20px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.cfar .detail input:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail input:focus ~ .inputBar:after,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus ~ .inputBar:after 
.cfar .detail select:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail select:focus ~ .inputBar:after {
 width: 50%;
}

.cfar .detail .answer { 
 display: inline-block;
 width: 114px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #ffffff;
 left: 133px;
 position: inherit;
}
/* custom css*/
span.error{
 /*display: none;*/
 color: red;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px !important;
 right: 0;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}  
.error_show {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
 color: red;
}
input:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
    background-color: none;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------
  contact form style 1
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.cfar-s1 .detail input,.cfar-s1 .detail textarea,.cfar-s1 .detail select {
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 position: relative;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 99;
}
.cfar-s1 .detail .inputBar {
 position: relative;
}
.cfar-s1 .detail .inputBar:before {
 content: "";
 height: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: -1px;
 background-color: #ff0000;
 width: 0;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.cfar-s1 .detail input:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar-s1 .detail textarea:focus ~ .inputBar:before {
 width: 100%;
}

.cfar-s1 .detail label {
 top: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #777777;
}
.message {
 flex-basis: 100% !important;
}
.btn-container {
 margin: 40px auto;
}
.btn-container .btn {
 border: none;
 background-color: #da4e5b;
 padding: 20px 75px;
 color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contactform1">
    <div id="note"></div>
      <form id="contact" method="post" action="">
      <div id="note"></div>
      <div class="detail">
       <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name" autocomplete="off" required />
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
       <span class="error">This field is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->
      <div class="detail">
       <input type="text" id="contact_email" name="email" autocomplete="off" required />
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->

       <label for="contact_email">Email</label>
       <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->
      <div class="detail">
       <input type="number" id="contact_phone" autocomplete="off" name="phone" required />
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <label for="contact_phone">Phone Number</label>
       <span class="error">A valid Phone number is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->
      <div class="detail">
       <input type="text" id="contact_enquiry" autocomplete="off" name="enquiry" required />
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <label for="contact_enquiry">I want to know about...</label>
       <span class="error">This field is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->
      <div class="detail message">
       <textarea type="text" id="contact_message" autocomplete="off" name="message" required></textarea>
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <label for="contact_message">Type your Message here</label>
       <span class="error">This field is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->

      <div class="detail">
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <input type="radio" id="contact_male" name="male" required />Male
       <input type="radio" id="contact_female" name="female" required />Female
       <span class="error">This field is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->
      

      <div class="detail">
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <input type="checkbox" id="contact_html" name="html" required />HTMl
       <input type="checkbox" id="contact_css" name="css" required />CSS
       <span class="error">This field is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->


      <div class="btn-container" id="submit_form">
       <a href="#">Submit</a>
      </div>  
     </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can tick both your radio buttons (you can be male and female)  -> put same name

Comment: The problem with radio buttons is their names. name both of them similar, something like `gender`. But what is the problem of checkboxes??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're validating all checkboxes and radiobuttons individually, while it's pretty obvious that you consider them together: the validity of 1 radiobutton depends on the checked-property of another radiobutton.

In order to fix this, you need to create a validation function that counts all radiobuttons that belong together, and count the checked-property to be 1.

Change your HTML for radiobuttons and checkbuttons so that it has a wrapped class:

```
<div class="detail gender">
    span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
    <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" />Male
    <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" />Female
    <span class="error">This field is required</span>
</div><!--detail-->
```

Note the "gender" class wrapping the radiobuttons. Also note how both radiobuttons have the same name (this will group the radiobuttons together in a browser, i.e. if you select one it will deselect the other one). The value attribute will be sent with the form when submitted for the "gender" field.

Now you can validate at least one of these buttons is validated by doing this at a given time (for instance in a click event or probably on the submit of the form)

```
var radiobuttons = $(".gender").find("input[type=radio]");
if(radiobuttons.prop("checked").length === 1) {
    // do valid stuff here
} else {
    // do invalid stuff here
}
```

This works for checkboxes too.

Comment: yeah, it will work but error message not showing.see in my code on submit.

Comment: I dont understand what you're saying, what is the error you're getting? did you implement what I described?

Answer (score 0):

They(radio buttons) must have same name. Name the something like `gender` and add value attribute to get the value for each like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('.success_msg').hide();

 /* name*/ 
 $('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var regex = /^([^0-9]*)$/;
  var is_name=regex.test(input.val());
  if(is_name){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
   
  }
 });
  
 /* E-mail */ 
 $('#contact_email').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var regex = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
  var is_email=regex.test(input.val());
  if(is_email){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* Phone */ 
 $('#contact_phone').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var regex =  /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  var is_phone=regex.test(input.val());
  if(is_phone){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* message*/
 $('#contact_message, #contact_enquiry').keyup(function(event) {
  var input=$(this);
  var message=$(this).val();
  if(message){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  } 
 });

 /* Radio button */


 $('#contact_male, #contact_female').click(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked")){
   $(this).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
     }
     else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
   $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
     }
 });

 /* Checkbox */


 // $('#contact_check').click(function(){
 //     if($(this).is(":checked")){
 //   $(this).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
 //     }
 //     else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
 //   $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
 //     }
 // });

 
  /* Submit */
 $("#submit_form").click(function(event){

  var form_data = $("#contact").serializeArray();

  var error_free = true;
  for (var input in form_data){
   var element = $("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name']);
   var valid = element.hasClass("valid");
   var error_element = $("span", element.parent());

   if (!valid){
    error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show"); error_free=false;
   }
   else{
    error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
   }
  }

  if (!error_free){
   event.preventDefault(); 
  }
  else{
   $('.success_msg').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
   $('input , textarea , select').val('').removeClass('valid');
   event.preventDefault();
  }

 });
   
});
```

```css
.success_msg {
    width: 350px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(213, 255, 187, 0.7);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
}
.iva-nav {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: all 0.74s ease;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
.iva-nav span {
 transform: translateZ(8px);
 -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
.iva-nav:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.4);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 50;
}
.iva-nav:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.4);
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 25;
}
.iva-nav:hover:before {
 transform: rotate(225deg);
 background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.6);
 border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.1);

}
.iva-nav:hover:after {
 transform: rotate(133deg);
 background-color: rgba(254, 180, 29, 0.6);
 border: 1px solid rgba(255, 225, 225, 0.1);
}
.fancy-heading-s1 {
 max-width: 1400px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 40px;
 padding: 25px 0;
 color: #ffffff;
} 
.fancy-heading-s2 {
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 color: #fff;
}
.fancy-title {
 display: block;
 font-size: 13px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.cfar-s1 .cfar-heading {
 text-align: center;
}

*:focus{ outline: none;}

.cfar {
 max-width: 1140px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cfar-s1 {
 padding: 40px 100px;
 background-color: #313439;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span {
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span:after {
 content: " . ";
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 transform: translateY(-15%);
 margin: 0 10px;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-title span:last-child:after {
 content: "";
 margin-right: 0;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-heading-s2 h2 {
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cfar-s1 .fancy-heading-s2 h2 span {
 color: #da4e5b;
}
.cfar-s1 form {
 padding: 30px 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.cfar .detail {
 position: relative;
 margin: 20px 0;
 flex-basis: 48%;
}

.cfar .detail input,.detail textarea,.detail select {
 display: block;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 padding: 5px 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.cfar option { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); }
.cfar .detail textarea {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 resize: none;
}

.cfar .detail label {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 5px;
 font-size: 16px;
 pointer-events: none;
 transition: all 0.43s ease-in-out;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 transition: all 0.43s ease-in-out;
}
.cfar .detail input:focus:after,.detail textarea:foucs:after,.detail select:focus:after,
.cfar .detail .inputBar:focus:before, 
.cfar .detail .inputBar:focus:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 0;
 background: red;
 height: 2px;
}

.cfar .detail .inputBar:after { right: 50%;}

.cfar .detail .inputBar:before { left: 50%;}

.cfar .detail input:focus ~ label,
.cfar .detail input:valid ~ label,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus ~ label,
.cfar .detail textarea:valid ~ label {
 top: -20px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.cfar .detail input:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail input:focus ~ .inputBar:after,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail textarea:focus ~ .inputBar:after 
.cfar .detail select:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar .detail select:focus ~ .inputBar:after {
 width: 50%;
}

.cfar .detail .answer { 
 display: inline-block;
 width: 114px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #ffffff;
 left: 133px;
 position: inherit;
}
/* custom css*/
span.error{
 /*display: none;*/
 color: red;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px !important;
 right: 0;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}  
.error_show {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
 color: red;
}
input:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
    background-color: none;
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------
  contact form style 1
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.cfar-s1 .detail input,.cfar-s1 .detail textarea,.cfar-s1 .detail select {
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
 position: relative;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 99;
}
.cfar-s1 .detail .inputBar {
 position: relative;
}
.cfar-s1 .detail .inputBar:before {
 content: "";
 height: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: -1px;
 background-color: #ff0000;
 width: 0;
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.cfar-s1 .detail input:focus ~ .inputBar:before,
.cfar-s1 .detail textarea:focus ~ .inputBar:before {
 width: 100%;
}

.cfar-s1 .detail label {
 top: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #777777;
}
.message {
 flex-basis: 100% !important;
}
.btn-container {
 margin: 40px auto;
}
.btn-container .btn {
 border: none;
 background-color: #da4e5b;
 padding: 20px 75px;
 color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contactform1">
     <div id="note"></div>
     <form id="contact" method="post" action="">

      <div id="note"></div>

      <div class="detail">
       <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name" autocomplete="off" required />
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <label for="contact_name">Name</label>
       <span class="error">This field is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->
      <div class="detail">
       <input type="text" id="contact_email" name="email" autocomplete="off" required />
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->

       <label for="contact_email">Email</label>
       <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->
      <div class="detail">
       <input type="number" id="contact_phone" autocomplete="off" name="phone" required />
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <label for="contact_phone">Phone Number</label>
       <span class="error">A valid Phone number is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->
      <div class="detail">
       <input type="text" id="contact_enquiry" autocomplete="off" name="enquiry" required />
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <label for="contact_enquiry">I want to know about...</label>
       <span class="error">This field is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->
      <div class="detail message">
       <textarea type="text" id="contact_message" autocomplete="off" name="message" required></textarea>
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <label for="contact_message">Type your Message here</label>
       <span class="error">This field is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->

      <div class="detail">
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <input type="radio" id="contact_male" value="male" name="gender" required />Male
       <input type="radio" id="contact_female" value="female" name="gender" required />Female
       <span class="error">This field is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->
      

      <div class="detail">
       <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
       <input type="checkbox" id="contact_html" name="html" required />HTMl
       <input type="checkbox" id="contact_css" name="css" required />CSS
       <span class="error">This field is required</span>
      </div><!--detail-->


      <div class="btn-container" id="submit_form">
       <a href="#">Submit</a>
      </div>  
     </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks I got that point but validation error message is not coming.according to my code `id` on submit `contact_` form-data i was taken so after `_` name should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same name, this way it is impossible to click them both.